# UDP Receiver code only receiving one packet

Tags: java, udp

Th following code only receives on packet of data.  I have sent different sizes of data to see if data is being received on the receiver.  I only get the first packet and I do not see any other packets.  What could be the cause of the missing packets.  Since I am receiving 12 bytes every time.  Do I need to clear the buffer or make it larger. What practices should I follow.

```
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class Reciever {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(2010);
      byte[] data = new byte[12];
      DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(data, 12);
      s.receive(p);
      System.out.println("got packet");
      ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(12).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
      bb.put(data);
      bb.rewind();
      System.out.println(bb.getFloat());
      System.out.println(bb.getFloat());
      System.out.println(bb.getFloat());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You receive only one UDP packet because you call `receive` only once and then exit. If more than one packet is sent you will receive one and the others are dropped and lost forever.

Add a loop to receive more than one packet:

```
try {
    DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(2010);
    byte[] data = new byte[12];
    DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(data, 12);
    while (true) {
        s.receive(p);
        System.out.println("got packet");
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(12).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        bb.put(data);
        bb.rewind();
        System.out.println(bb.getFloat());
        System.out.println(bb.getFloat());
        System.out.println(bb.getFloat());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what happens if you don't know the size of the packet coming in.  In this code the byte size is 12.  I have tested the code change the buffer size to bigger then 12 and I get a buffer flow exception

Comment: With datagrams you have to know how big the biggest packet can be. Once you have received it you can check the size of the packet with the `getLength` method.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding a while loop and moving the 
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(2010);
byte[] data = new byte[12]; outside the loop